# DATA maniplation : make time series data

Tags: r

t1<-c(196613,196713, 196813, 196913, 197013, 197113, 197213, 197301, 197302 ,197303,197304,197305,197306,197307,197308,197309 ,197310 ,197311 ,197312)

I want to remove xxxx13 and make time series monthly data set.

```
`last two digits` <- function(x) { return(substring(as.character(x),   nchar(x)-1, nchar(x))) }

filter(t1, `last two digits`(t1)<13)


date <- as.Date(as.character((t1)),format="%Y%m")
```

---

### I used dplyr and wrote code like above, however function  `last two digits` read "TRUE" OR "FALSE" instead numeric data.

After fixed t[t%%100<13] and run " date", but the results are all "NA".
Could you help me to fix it, please?

Comment: Please use syntactically valid function names. Also, why do you use string processing for numerical data?

Comment: E.g. have a look at `t1 %% 100` and `t1 %/% 100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not apparent from your question, but I suspect you want this:

```
t1[t1 %% 100 < 13]
#[1] 197301 197302 197303 197304 197305 197306 197307 197308 197309 197310 197311 197312
```

Comment: Thanks, I want this. Do you have an idea to covert times series format?

Comment: No, because what you have seems to be some time information, i.e., possibly the index of a time series. There is no actual time series data here.